# How to get active state of link (in CSS) to work?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Can't see why *a:active* is not working!
Want link button to remain blue (#1770b8) when active, same as hover state.
[Tried in Firefox, IE and Chrome]

Have I done something silly?!

a:hover
 - Hover works fine.

a:link 
 - Button is black, so this works.

a:visited
 - Button stays black (does not default to grey) so this works.

```
.woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation li a:link,
.woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation li a:visited {
    padding:5px;
    display:block;
    width:150px;
    color:#ffffff;
    background-color:#000 !important;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
.woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation li a:hover,
.woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation li a:active {
    padding:5px;
    display:block;
    width:150px;    
    color:#ffffff;        
    background-color:#1770b8 !important;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: Please construct a [mcve] by editing your post and creating a [HTML/CSS snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) that reproduces your issue. In my case, I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: [Working](https://jsfiddle.net/wzyme8n0/) with your styles. You might have some other styles which are overriding. Inspect and check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're telling the the active link to have a foreground `color` of white and a `background-color` which is the same as the hover state (the bluish color, #1770b8). This makes it impossible to see the difference in states.

If you separate the `:active` state into a new style instruction, you can see it's working. For example, I'll set the active foreground color of the link to red:

```css
.woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation li a:link,
.woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation li a:visited {
  padding: 5px;
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #000 !important;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation li a:hover {
  padding: 5px;
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #1770b8 !important;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation li a:active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation">
  <li><a href="#">test link</a></li>
</div>
```

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/upomysez/

Comment: Thanks, couldn't see the wood for the trees!!! Also, think i've been conflating '.current' with ':active' - after searching on here think that's bit more work with php/jquery... think i'll leave it as is for now.

Comment: @sham No problem. If you're happy with the answer, I'd love if you could set it as the chosen answer.